# How to integrate hyperbolic function $\frac{1-\sin(x)}{1+\sin(x)}$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, hyperbolic-functions

I'm trying to find a primitive of $ \frac{1-\sin(x)}{1+\sin(x)} $. By changing the variable to $t=\tan(\frac{x}{2})$ and letting $\sin(x) = \frac{2t}{1+t^2}$ I get the following integral:

\begin{align}
& \int \frac{1-\sin(x)}{1+\sin(x)} \, dx \\[8pt] = {} & \int \frac{ 1-\frac{2t}{1+t^2} } { 1+ \frac{2t}{1+t^2} } \frac{2}{1+t^2} \, dt \\[8pt]
= {} & 2\int \frac{ t^2 -2t +1 }{ (t^2 +2t+1)(t^2 + 1) } \, dt \\[8pt]
= {} & 2\int \frac{t^2 -2t +1 }{(t+1)^2(t^2+1)} \, dt \end{align}

Now I know that I could do a partial fraction expansion. I would get 3 simpler fraction but I also know that the result contains only two fraction by calculating it in xcas: $$ \int \frac{1-\sin(x)}{1+\sin(x)} \, dx = 2\left(-\frac{2}{\tan(\frac{x}{2}) +1} - \frac{x}{2}\right) $$
Is there an easier way to calculate this primitive ?

Comment: Write sin(x)−1 as sin(x)+1−2 and split:

Comment: Do you know $(1-\sin x)/(1+\sin x)=\tan^2((\pi/4)-(x/2))$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\int\frac{1-\sin x}{1+\sin x}dx &= \int\left(\frac2{1+\sin x}-1\right)\,dx
\\&= \int\frac2{1+\frac{2t}{1+t^2}}\cdot\frac2{1+t^2}\,dt-x
\\&= \int\frac4{1+2t+t^2}\,dt-x
\\&= \int\frac4{(t+1)^2}\,d(t+1)-x
\\&= -\frac4{t+1}-x
\\&= -\frac4{\tan\frac x2+1}-x
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** Multiply the integrand for $\frac{1-\sin x}{1 - \sin x}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
$$\frac{\sin(x)-1}{\sin(x)+1}=1-\frac{2}{\sin(x)+1}$$
From this evaluate $\frac{2}{\sin(x)+1}$ using trigonometric/hyperbolic identities

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from your work, you could still use partial fraction. The partial fraction expansion would actually only have $2$ simple fractions. Specifically, $$\frac{t^2 -2t +1 }{(t+1)^2(t^2+1)} = \frac{2}{(t+1)^2}-\frac{1}{t^2+1}$$

Can you finish from here?

Comment: Am I not supposed to have something like this: $ \frac{t^2 -2t +1}{(t+1)^2(t^2+1)} = \frac{a}{(t+1)} + \frac{b}{(t+1)^2} + \frac{ct +d}{t^2 +1} $ with $(a,b,c,d) \in \mathbb{R}^4 $

Comment: @CorentinF Yes, but $a$ and $c$ would be equal to $0$ in this specific case, so it works out nicely.

Comment: I can't find your result. I did find $b=2$ and $a=-c$  and then I'm stuck trying to find $c$ and $d$. I tried to replace $t$ by $i$ but then I find myself diving by 0 because of $\frac{ct+d}{t^2+1}$. How did you find $d=-1$ ?

Comment: Substitute other values of $t$ and solve the equations. They might be ugly, but very effective.

Comment: @CorentinF Given that $\frac{t^2-2t+1}{(t+1)^2(t^2+1)} = \frac{a}{t+1} + \frac{2}{(t+1)^2} + \frac{-at + d}{t^2+1}$, we can multiply by $(t+1)^2(t^2+1)$ on both sides to get $t^2-2t+1 = (t+1)(t^2+1)a + 2(t^2+1) + (t+1)^2(-at+d)$. Then setting the coefficients of $t^2, t, 1$ equal on both sides yields $1=a+2+d-2a, -2=a+2d-a, 1=a+2+d$. You can then solve for $a, d$ to get $a = 0, d=-1$.

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle \frac{1-sinx}{1+sinx}=\frac{2}{1+sinx}-1=\frac{2}{(sin\frac{x}{2}+cos\frac{x}{2})^{2}}-1$

$\displaystyle =\frac{1}{cos^{2}(\frac{x}{2}-\frac{\pi}{4})}-1=tan^{2}(\frac{x}{2}-\frac{\pi}{4})$

$\displaystyle \theta=\frac{x}{2}-\frac{\pi}{4}\Rightarrow 2d\theta=dx$

$\displaystyle z=tan\theta\Rightarrow dz=(1+tan^{2}\theta)d\theta $

$\displaystyle dz-d\theta=tan^{2}\theta d\theta=d(z-\theta)$

$\displaystyle \int\frac{1-sinx}{1+sinx}dx=2\int tan^{2}\theta d\theta=2\int d(z-\theta)=2z-2\theta+c$
$\displaystyle \int\frac{1-sinx}{1+sinx}=2tan(\frac{x}{2}-\frac{\pi}{4})-2(\frac{x}{2}-\frac{\pi}{4})+c=2tan(\frac{x}{2}-\frac{\pi}{4})-x+C$